# Nodejs Sequelize relationships not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create system where user can be interested in products. There are many products and several users can be interested about same product. I have followed a tutorial (https://github.com/ianmunrobot/1702-express-review) and modified it to my purposes to create seed.js script which creates following tables to db: Interests, Users, Products using database.js as config. Anyway when I'm trying to use same database.js file with rest of my project Im getting an error.

User.js

```
// The User model.
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const config = require('../config');
const db = require('../database');
const Product = require('./Product');

// 1: The model schema.
const modelDefinition = {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  role: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
};

// 2: The model options.
const modelOptions = {
  instanceMethods: {
    comparePasswords: comparePasswords,
  },
  hooks: {
    beforeValidate: hashPassword
  },
};

// 3: Define the User model.
const UserModel = db.define('User', modelDefinition, modelOptions);

// Compares two passwords.
function comparePasswords(password, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function (error, isMatch) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }

    return callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}

// Hashes the password for a user object.
function hashPassword(user) {
  if (user.changed('password')) {
    return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(function (password) {
      user.password = password;
    });
  }
}

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Products.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database');

const User = require('./User');

const ProductModel = db.define('Product', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  price: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
});

module.exports = ProductModel;
```

database.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('./config');

const db = new Sequelize(
  config.db.name,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.details,
);

module.exports = db;

const User = require('./models/User.js');
const Product = require('./models/Product.js');

Product.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'users', through: 'Interests' });
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const hookJWTStrategy = require('./passportStrategy');

const routes = require('./routes/index');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type,         Authorization, x-id, Content-Length, X-Requested-with');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,         OPTIONS');
  next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(passport.initialize());

// Hook the passport JWT strategy.
hookJWTStrategy(passport);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Expected results is that user could be interested in products. The interests should be in Interests table and user should be able to be interested in many products.

Error:

```
  Error: Product.belongsToMany called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model
at Model.Mixin.belongsToMany (/home/mikko/git/s/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:252:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mikko/git/s/database.js:17:9)
```

Comment: can you post the contents of User.js?

Comment: I added User.js and Product.js

Comment: `through` should be a sequelize model, not a string. That's what the error says

Comment: Thank you but I have followed the example where it has been used in the same way: https://github.com/ianmunrobot/1702-express-review/blob/master/db.js

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to add a comment due to having a reputation less than 50.  My guess would be that the User model is not ready at the time you are trying to use it.  Can you post your app.js or equivalent?  I suspect there may be a mismatch between a 'require' somewhere and your filenames.

I used the examples you have provided above and the following line in app.js to require database.js:

```
    var db = require('./database');
```

This works fine for me.

However, if I change it to (Uppercase 'D'):

```
    var db = require('./Database');
```

I am able to reproduce the error you are experiencing.

You would need to call db.sync() to sync your defined models to the DB.

```
      db.sync({force: false})
        .then(message => {
            console.log('db synced');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            throw err;
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added app.js. Isn't it enough to require database in model files?

Comment: You need to call db.sync() to sync your defined models to the DB.